# Roxygen - R6 methods

Tags: r, roxygen2, r6

I'm trying to generate some reasonable documentation for R6 classes.  Here's an example:

```
##' GroveR class object
##' @importFrom R6 R6Class
##' @export
GroveR <- R6Class(
  portable = FALSE,
  private = list(
    fileRoot = ".",
    artDefs = list(),
    memCache = list()
  )
)

.public  <- function(...) GroveR$set("public",  ...)

#' Do a thing
#'
#' @name myMethod
#' @usage
#' myMethod(name, deps, create, retrieve, checkTime,
#'          store, clobber=FALSE)
#'
#' @param name name of the artifact
#' @param deps names of other artifacts this artifact depends on
#' @param create function to create this artifact object from its dependency objects
#' @param retrieve function to retrieve this artifact from cache
#' @param checkTime function to fetch the time of last update for this artifact
#' @param store function to store this artifact to cache
#' @param clobber whether to allow redefinition of this artifact if it is already defined
.public("myMethod", function(name, deps, create, retrieve, checkTime, store, clobber=FALSE) {
  # ...body...
}

#' Do a similar thing
#'
#' @name myOtherMethod
#' myOtherMethod(name, deps, create, path, readFun=readRDS,
#'               writeFun=saveRDS, ...)
#'
#' @inheritParams myMethod  // TODO Doesn't work yet
#' @param path path to cached file
#' @param readFun function to read file from disk
#' @param writeFun function to write file to disk
#' @param ... further arguments passed to \link{myMethod}
.public("myOtherMethod", function(name, deps, create, path, readFun=readRDS, writeFun=saveRDS, ...) {
  # ...body...
}
```

`.public()` is a helper function I've written for defining R6 methods.

There are several things not working here:

- The `@inheritParams` directive is not working, the `name` and `deps` and `create` argument for `myOtherMethod()` are not being inherited.  This generates `R CMD check` warnings like `Undocumented arguments in documentation object 'myOtherMethod'
  ‘name’ ‘deps’ ‘create’`
- I'm adding the `@usage` directive manually, because Roxygen can't figure out (quite reasonably) how to parse my method definitions.  Is there a better way to do this?
- In `R CMD check`, I get warnings about `Functions or methods with usage in documentation object 'myMethod' but not in code:
  myMethod`

Is there a more fruitful direction for me to go?  Should I try documenting a `NULL` object instead of my `.public` calls?  What would that look like?

Comment: I turned this question into https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/835 , to see whether that audience is more interested.